# Creating Dynamic HTML tables using Joomla database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, joomla

**Mechanism of My Code** :

My code executes a SQL query which selects all the rows whose USERNAME column contains the value of username whose presently logged into my website.

**What I Am Trying To Achieve** ?

I want to show these rows as HTML tables but i want them to dynamic. I mean, if only 1 row was found against the logged in user, then only a HTML table of 1 row should be created & if 5 rows are found against the logged in user, then a HTML table of 5 rows should be created.

**This Is My Code** :

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__report'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('username') . " = ". $db->quote($user->username));
$db->setQuery($query);

$row = $db->loadRow();

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th> Article Name </th>
<th> Report Data </th>
<tr>
<tr>
<td> #name_of_the_article </td>
<td> #report_data_of_the_article </td>

</tr>
</table>";
```

What do i need to add/edit to my code, to achieve this..?

Comment: Please see the following: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/printing-query-result-set-as-a-html-table/1080#1080

Comment: i had already seen it. can you please answer in context of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. Based on the answer I wrote on JSE, but using your code.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__report'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('username') . " = ". $db->quote($user->username));
$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '  <th>Article Name </th>';
echo '  <th>Report Data </th>';
echo '</tr>';  
      foreach($rows as $row) {
          echo '<tr><td>' . $row->name . '</td><td>' . $row->report_data . '</td></tr>';
      }
echo '</table>';
```

As you can see, I've used `$row->name` and `$row->report_data`, but you might need to change these depending on the columns names of the database.

Comment: Change 
$rows = $db->loadrow(); 
to
$rows = $db->loadRowList();

Only then it works! :)

Comment: damn! i was going nuts because of this one line. Saibbyweb is correct..It only works with $rows = $db->loadRowList();
Anyways thanks Lodder for the code.

Comment: @user3706687 - I've updated the code with more details. Should work as expected now

Comment: Dont know about this loadObjectList but your previous code worked for me with that little change { $rows = $db->loadrow(); }